# SQL for Spring Web Site Paging using Maria DB

Tags: mariadb, spring-mybatis

my web site was made by Spring framework.
and also using Mybatis.

in my web site, has bulletin board page.
and here is the board table.

**TB_BOARD**

```
seq(pk), user_seq, title, category, content, reg_time
```

now i want apply paging.
so i checked Maria DB document.
they said use pk instead of offset.
okay, i understand.. but there is problem.

if my bulletin board page has only the previous and next buttons, there is no problem.
i will write my SQL like this:

**next**

```
select * from TB_BOARD where seq < #{last_seq} order by seq desc limit 5
```

**previos**

```
select * from TB_BOARD where seq >= #{last_seq} order by seq desc limit 5
```

but if bulletin page has a numbered paging button?
[1][2][3][4][5]

and someone clicked [4] button..how do i get the records for [4] button?
in my think, records can be changed(update, delete), seq will be no longer sequential.
so it is impossible to predict.

is not there any way to do this without "select @rownum"?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'previos' query needs `ASC`, not `DESC` if I understand `seq` correctly.

If you are going to have `[1][2]...` with all pages possible, you are asking for trouble.  I will assume you list only the next and previous, say, 5 pages.  That is, if you are on page 13, the buttons will show 8..18.  (Plus, perhaps, `[first]` and `[last]`.

You must not use a hard-coded "sequence" number.  Instead, use a `datetime` or other thing that has the same effect

As for `INSERTs` and `DELETEs`, "next" and "previous" can be made to work "correctly", but jumping to an arbitrary page is ambiguous because of changes that could have happened.

3 pages head of the current one is `seq < $this ORDER BY seq DESC LIMIT 15,5` (or something like that.

More on pagination [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).